# UITableView: Scroll to a row based on a string?

Tags: uitableview

Case: I am adding a new record to a table.

Goal: Following the add, I'd like to scroll my tableView to the new record. Is this possible?
Alternative: ask user to search for new record.
Alternative 2: set a predicate for the new record, and reload only the new record.

Thanks for any methods/ideas.

Comment: Assuming you have an array somewhere that acts as a data source for the table, you can find the new record's offset in the array, create an index path from that, and call the table view's `scrollToRow` function.

Comment: I like that idea. Thanks